# Transfer values from json file to vue2 google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a [simple vue project](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jp10041qv5).

There is a google map that I connect using [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps).

And [there is json file (or rather data.php)](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jp10041qv5) :

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "name": "Location 1",
      "adress": "215 West Girard Avenue 19123",
      "location": {
        "lat": "39.9695601",
        "lon": "-75.1395161"
      },
      "lable": "200",
      "prev": "img-1.png"
    },
    { ...
```

File **GoogleMap.vue --> template:**

```
<template>  
    <div class="container">    
        <gmap-map id="map" v-bind="options">
            <gmap-marker
                :key="index"
                v-for="(m, index) in markers"
                :position="m.position"
                :clickable="true"
                :draggable="true"
                :label="m.label"
                @click="openWindow"

            />
            <gmap-info-window 
                @closeclick="window_open=false" 
                :opened="window_open" 
                :position="infowindow"
                :options="{
                  pixelOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0
                  }
                }"
            >
                Hello world!
            </gmap-info-window> 
        </gmap-map>
    </div>  
</template>
```

File **GoogleMap.vue --> script:**

```
import { gmapApi } from "vue2-google-maps";

export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      //map: null,
      options: {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
          lat: 39.9995601,
          lng: -75.1395161
        },
        mapTypeId: "roadmap"
      },
      markers: [
        {
          label: "200",
          position: { lat: 39.9695601, lng: -75.1395161 }
        },
        {
          label: "30",
          position: { lat: 40.034038, lng: -75.145223 }
        },
        {
          label: "45",
          position: { lat: 39.9713524, lng: -75.159036 }
        }
      ],
      info_marker: null,
      infowindow: {
        lat: 39.9995601,
        lng: -75.1395161
      },
      window_open: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    google: gmapApi
  },
  watch: {},
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      console.log("init");
    },
    openWindow() {
      console.log(this);
      this.window_open = true;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.initialize();
  }
};
```

............................................................................................................................................................................................................

**Question:** How to `markers: [        {` transfer values from **data.php** (lat, lng, lable)?

Comment: `data.php` contains no PHP and has only a JSON object in it. Why does the file have the `.php` extension instead of `.json`?

Comment: @tony19, this is my personal task. I thought it doesn't matter, but I see that it's important. With json https://codesandbox.io/embed/5vq9q3kqmk ) P.S: Sorry for my english

Comment: It matters because the extension of the imported file determines which webpack loader is used and how you import the data. Plus, it just doesn't make sense to give a file an extension that doesn't apply. If the correct file extension were used, you'd be able to take advantage of IDE syntax highlighting, formatting, and linting specifically for `.json` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the JSON file like so:

```
import { default as locations } from '/path/to/json/file.json`
```

Then, you can create a `markers` computed property:

```
computed: {
  markers() {
    return locations.map(({ label, location: { lat, lon }}) => ({
     label,
     position: {
       lat: Number.parseFloat(lat),
       lng: Number.parseFloat(lon)
     }
    }))
  }
}
```

There are a couple of things to be corrected:

- `address` is misspelled in the JSON file.
- `label` is misspelled in the JSON file.

---

Edit:

If a `php` file is used, apparently you'll need to use `JSON.parse`.

### [**Revised CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-og0tg)

Comment: this is amazing) Thank you!